# are unproven theories compatible with Islam?!!

Tags: discussion

what can we do when facing some questions that are completely wrong! you might've read some questions comparing Islamic viewpoint with an unproven theory! wouldn't it be ridiculous to compare Islam with some theories which have not been proven to be right?

this is one of them: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/14840/evolution-and-islam/14923#14923

we are not even sure that the "evolution" existed so how possibly could we go into details of an unproven theory and try to reconcile it with another idea?!

Comment: As Shog9 has made clear, the thread in question made no premises regarding the validity of evolution. Although it is deliciously ironic that this question of *yours* is based on a false premise (i.e. that evolution is not well-established), so should we tolerate *this* question?

Answer (score 3):

This is not *inherently* a problem.

Consider a much more mundane scenario, such as one might face in a police investigation: a series of events resulted in a result that is observable to all (for instance, the theft of a well-documented item, or a murder); the goal is to determine the nature of those events. Tools available include:

- Eyewitness testimony
- Direct observation of evidence left at the scene
- Knowledge gained from observing similar scenarios

From these, theories are developed that attempt to explain the result. These theories may align with the available evidence and prior knowledge, or they may dispute some of it as irrelevant or even misleading. Witnesses can be mistaken or duplicitous, evidence can be fabricated or contaminated, prior knowledge can be wrong... Any evidence must either support a given theory, contradict it, or be deemed irrelevant to it. *This* is not subjective. You may debate the validity of the theory or the evidence, but the relationship (if any) between the two should be established and can be documented.

...*If* that had been the nature of the question, then I would say it is reasonable - although not necessary on-topic here. If the question had constrained itself to actual, documented Islamic teachings, then it would have been able to fulfill both requirements.

**But the question you reference did neither.** It was both extremely broad (for which reason I closed it) and failed to actually be *about Islam!* No, "some unidentified people who claim to be followers of Islam believe X" is not a reasonable foundation on which to build a question - you're essentially asking askers to explain a vague claim that can (and will) change to fit the desires of those answering and/or the changing whims of the asker who can't be bothered to describe *what he actually wants*.

Comment: We will have to agree to disagree on whether my question was "extremely broad" but in what way was it not "about Islam"? A currently active thread in Islam.SE is whether a guy can marry his sister-in-law. That isn't *about* Islam.

Comment: I don't know which question you're talking about; if you feel it's inappropriate, then flag it or raise a separate discussion about it. I explained the problems with the question being discussed *here* in my answer above: questions about the opinions of people who happen to also follow Islam are not inherently questions about Islam - you have to actually be seeking Islamic teachings.

Answer (score -1):

Evolution is possibly the best-tested idea that science has ever seen. It has been observed in laboratories over and over. It has been observed in the wild - in animal colonies and plant colonies. There is even evidence of it happening in humans.

Not believing in evolution would be like not believing in gravity, or not believing in photosynthesis.

So if Islam were not compatible with evolution, then it is Islam that would have the problem. Therefore, it is only natural for intelligent Muslims to seek answers to such a question - how do I reconcile the apparent contradiction between Adam and Hawa as created beings, and the overwhelming evidence that humans have evolved from apes. Being able to reconcile these two ideas is therefore important to all thoughtful Muslims, and is absolutely related to Islam. There is no doubt that this question is on-topic.